# How do I display selected item from array list on textview

Tags: java, android, arraylist, onclicklistener

```
public class trackActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_track);

        TextView track01 = findViewById(R.id.trackView1);
        track01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent tracksIntent = new Intent(trackActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(tracksIntent);enter code here
            }
        });
```

Hello I am new to Android and Java. I have created a array list of tracks and set the `onclicklistener` to go back to main activity when the array list are clicked. I also want to display that clicked array list as a `textview` on the main activity XML but I cannot get it to work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: To clarify - your problem is that you can't get the selected text into the main activity? Or you don't know how to display it? Please describe exactly what you can't get to work, what you've tried, and any error messages you are getting.

Comment: I don't know how to display the texts in the array list in the main activity. For example I have 7 tracks starting from track 01 and when I press the track 01 I want to display that track 01 in the main activity as a textview and when I press track 02 I want the display track 02.

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the clicked text in your arraylist, you must assign your arraylist to a listview or recyclerview (you have to display it first).

Then you will simply create a onClickListener for the listview or recyclerview. Within that method, you will see the int position (this is the number of the item the user selected from your list).
Then you will simply get the text in that position.

If you have already created listview, I would suggest you to paste the code here please for further clarification or answers.

Answer (score 0):

From MainActivity You can **startActivityForResult(TrackActivity**),
then by selecting a track setResult with track_name string & finish() the TrackActivity ...

Now on MainActivity you can get track Name string in **onActivityResult** section & display it